# Magento2: Custom module tab css issue

Tags: magento2

I am adding CSS to hide the custom module tab **settings, abandoned cart settings** but when I opening the general tab then CSS is removed at the same time.

[image]

```
.admin__page-nav.mkt-tab ._collapsible+.admin__page-nav-items .grazitti_settings { display: none; }
```

[image]

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: What css you have written?

Comment: updated comment

Comment: On which file you have added the css?

Comment: app\code\abc\Mkt\view\adminhtml\templates\system\config\validation.phtml

Comment: Are you able to see it in view source page? I think its not loading in your page

Comment: yes its not loading but this is working on my custom tab when i click on general it doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102711/discussion-between-sukumar-gorai-and-shiwani).

Comment: @Shiwani can you specify, what you are trying to archive here?

Comment: share me the details here same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***As per the discussion over chat group:***

You have added your xml code to below location:

> app\code\abc\Mkt\view\adminhtml\layout\adminhtml_system_config_edit_section_custom_handler.xml

**OR**

> app\code\abc\Mkt\view\adminhtml\layout\adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml

Location is correct but xml file name is wrong. As you have created this custom handler only for your section which will not call on other tabs and sections. So you need to rename the xml name from **adminhtml_system_config_edit_section_custom_handler.xml** to **default.xml** or **adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml** so that it will call on every page of Magento admin.
File location:

> app\code\abc\Mkt\view\adminhtml\layout\default.xml

with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" name="custom_validation" template="abc_Mkt::system/config/validation.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution!